# Gmail: jump to all emails just after the one I searched for?

Tags: gmail, search

In Gmail, I go through all emails starting from the last one, and I make sure none of them needs answering. If I find one that needs answering, I answer it, but then I lose track of where it was in the list, to keep going through the ones after that. How can I search for that email and then jump to "see all" again from that point on?

For example, I go through 1120 emails, I answer the 1120th, but then I want to go back to reading 1121th and subsequent. How can I quickly jump to email 1120th then go to all the other older ones, without having to manually go to 1120th in batches of 50?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can increase the number of conversations per page to 100 by going into `Settings -> General` (the first tab) and changing the number in `Maximum page size` (2nd from the top).
2. The new interface also has human-readable pagination links: `http://mail.google.com/mail/#all/p2`

Also, if you find yourself going through 1,100 emails, you should really consider [Inbox Zero](http://inboxzero.com/), using labels, and creating filters - it will save you time looking for emails.

Comment: I realised now I can also do the pagination URL on the new interface, so this is now the best answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Either `back to inbox` or `older` or `newer` will work at going back to where you were[image]

Comment: I just found out that I can bring back the old interface, which allows me to manually jump to a specific page, like so:    https://mail.google.com/mail/?yaddayadda/in%3ainbox/p20

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I can bring back the old interface, which allows me to manually jump to a specific page, like so: `mail.google.com/mail/?yaddayadda/in%3ainbox/p20`

Comment: This won't last for long, as the old interface will be phased out in the near future.